# Either $U$ or $U^\perp$ has a non-negative vector with positive first component

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve the following question: Given a subspace $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ and its orthogonal complement $U^\perp = \{v \in \mathbb R^n: u \cdot v = 0 \ \forall u \in U\}$ show that exactly one of the following statements is true:

1.) There exists a vector $\xi \in U$ with $\xi \ge 0$ (interpreted component-wise) and $\xi_1 >0$

2.) There exists a vector $\eta \in U^\perp$ with $\eta \ge 0$ (interpreted component-wise) and $\eta_1 >0$

The hint given is to describe $U$ as follows
$$U= \{ \begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ \tilde{u} \end{pmatrix}:M\tilde{u} = u_1 w\}$$
where $M$ is a suitable matrix and $w$ is a suitable vector. The hint goes on to say that I should use the Farkas Lemma on this representation of $U$.

My ideas so far: I was able to show that it is not possible for 1.) and 2.) to be true at the same time, that was easy. Now I have to show that one of them is always true. For finding a "suitable" matrix and vector $M$ and $w$ I thougt about the following: Every subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ can be described as the solutions of a homogenous system of linear equations, so there is a matrix that satisfies $U= \{x: Ax=0\}$. Using that we could write $U= \{x: (A_2, \dots, A_n)(x_2, \dots, x_n)^T = x_1 \cdot (-A_1)\}$
where $A_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. This idea would give $M=(A_2, \dots, A_n)$ and $w= -A_1$ but I am not sure if this is the right "suitable" matrix and vector.

The version of Farkas that I know is as follows: There is an $x \in \mathbb R^n, x\ge 0$ with $Ax=b$ iff $y^Tb \ge 0$ holds true for all $y \in \mathbb R^m$ with $y^TA \ge 0$.

My idea was to use Farkas with my matrix $M$ and say the following: Suppose 1.) is not true, so there is no vector $\tilde{u} \ge 0$ s.t. $M\tilde{u} = u_1w$. This implies that there is a vector $y \in \mathbb R^m$ with $y^Tu_1w <0$ although $y^TM \ge 0$. But I get stuck here. How can I go on from here? I obviously have to use the orthoganality of $U$ and $U^\perp$ at some point, but I can't see where. The $y$ we obtain from my use of Farkas doesn't help me at the moment, or maybe I am just not seeing it...

Any help on this problem is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried doing this with induction on $n$?

Comment: @user8675309 no, I haven't so far, but I will try it. Maybe it will work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it myself.

Observe that the rows of the matrix $A$ are all elements in $U^\perp$, because $Ax=0$ for $x \in U$ implies, that $A_i x =0$ for the rows $A_i$ of $A$. Therefore we get that $y^TA \in U^\perp$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^m$ because $y^TA$ is just a linear combination of the rows of $A$. That being said, let's use the $y$ given by Farkas Lemma (as described in the question).

We get $y^TA = y^T(-w|M) = (-y^Tw, y^TM) \in U^\perp$
where $-y^Tw >0$ because of $y^Tu_1w <0$ and $u_1 >0$ and $y^TM \ge 0$. That means that we found a vector in $U^\perp$ that satisfies 2.). And so the question is solved. Do you see any mistakes?